# SpringMVC "basic attribute type should not be Agent"

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am new to spring, I encounter a problem saying that the basic attribute should not be Agent (One of the entity class) in spring.

Here is my Customer class code (which contains Agent as an attribute inside it):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iV1Zz.png)

Here is how Agent is defined:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuZDl.png)

Here is the code for User:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGqMY.png)

Comment: Please don't post images of code, errors, or logs; see [ask]

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by annotating @OneToMany on the other side (Which is the Agent class)